# How to get a new NSIndexPath for tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView`. And I want to create a new custom delete action! But it requires a new `indexPath`. How get a new `indexPath`?

Here's my code:

```
func newFunction(sender:UIButton) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It works. But only deletes first object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every type in the framework exposes an initializer for you to use to create an instance of that type.

If you start to type the type name, `NSIndexPath`, you will see that Xcode suggests you use one of these:

[image]

If you want to delete a table cell in a specific section and a specific row, it is the best to use the fourth initializer overload.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

This will create an index path that corresponds to the first row in the first section. Indices always start at 0!

Here's a tip, each time you want to create an instance of a type, type the type name and selects an initializer that best suits your needs. Give it the needed parameter(s) and assign that to a constant or a variable.

Simple as that!